# Auto Suggestion dropdown in Angular when type @

Tags: angular

I want to implement functionality like autocomplete dropdown in Angular 8.
I am having a text box in which I will type any message that I will send to the user. if I type `"@"` then it should give me all the suggestions of the username that are available at that current time(which I will receive from the web service or I will have a manually created JSON data).

I have gone through the angular-mention but it is not useful in my case so I cannot use this.

Can anyone help me in this or can anyone provide me any helpful link?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

- Use `HostListener` on textbox for `@`.
- If any value matches through service, make a virtual dropdown visible.
- On dropdown selection, append its value to textbox.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand it correctly you want to load all the available usernames when you type the "@". It can vary on your implementation but I would put a checking before calling the web service and replace the "@" with a null / empty string (whichever fits your username filtering method better) to return all the available usernames.

It would be easier to assist you if you could share some code to see where you are standing. But the default approach would be to replace the @ with some default value, to get an "unfiltered" result from the service.

However, please be **very** carefull with loading **ALL** the available usernames. In most cases it is more appropriate to use a paginated query, and load only 5 / 10 / 100 results at once (depending on the usecase, and I would not really go above 1000). I think it is unnecessary and generally a bad practise to load more than 5 / 10 items for an autocomplete dropdown at once.